# When can tags be merged or made synonym?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have recently asked [a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55264/how-to-measure-a-solid-solid-surface-energy) about the surface energy of solids when only the [surface-tension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface-tension) tag was still available. Now there is also a [surface-energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface-energy) tag which is, in my opinion a more broad term which also includes effects in solids, but pretty much equivalent to surface-tension for liquids.

Is it a good idea to merge the tags in to 1 [surface-energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface-energy) tag, or make them synonyms?!

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451 and http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4007/2451

Answer (score 1):

I would just merge [surface-energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface-energy) -->[surface-tension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface-tension) with a synonym. No need for two tags talking about more or less the same phenomenon.

(I'll wait for anyone who wants to object for now)